# Delphi and WMI Networking

Tags: delphi, networking, wmi

for an application i'm writing, i need to change some parameters of
the network adapter, including enabling/disabling DHCP.
For this purpose, i'm using the "SetIpConfig" command from this source code:

[SetIPConfig](http://delphi.borlandforum.com/impboard/impboard.dll?action=read&db=del_tip&no=204)

It works very well and does what i need if the network adapter is connected.
The problem is that i cannot enable DHCP if  the LAN cable is unplugged,
while i can correctly change other parameters such as IP or Gateway.
When i try to enable dhcp, while network adapter is disconnected, i
get the ole error:

> 94 Path, file, or object not found

I think it should work anyway, even if the network card is disconnected, because
i can do this correctly, going into the network card/ip properties window (using XP).

HERE IS DESCRIBED EXACTLY MY PROBLEM:

http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/515984-c-enabling-dhcp-on-nic-through-wmi/

as that guy did, i tried to change directly the register keys to activate
the DHCP but, even if on the network adapter properties, the value
was changed correctly, the NIC behaved like nothing was changed, like
the changes were not "applied" to it.

Here another topic related:

www.winvistatips.com/wmi-config-fails-ethernet-cable-unplugged-t181330.html

They suggest to disable dhcpsense putting a key into
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
named DisableDHCPMediaSense (DWORD) and setting it to 1.

Ok..it works now, i didn't try the full dhcp functionality, just i've seen that
it can be enabled with nic unplugged but, as someone wrote, i don't think
disabling dhcp sense is a great idea.
It means that the dhcp client cannot know the connection status, so i think
that it could have troubles in renewing leases if the connection drops, then
is estabilished again.

OS: XP SP3
Language:DelphiXE

What's wrong ?
Many thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your problem [`this way`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). It will confirm the right answer to the future visitors with the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This it seems a WMI limitation (or bug?) when the device is disconnected (sometime ago I saw similar reports in another forums as well). As workaround and just for this particular case (when the device is not connected) you can try using the undocumented `DhcpNotifyConfigChange` function or using directly the windows registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{Adapter-guid_goes_here}
```

Comment: Ok, it works!
you have first to change the registry entries for your adapter,
then invoking DhcpNotifyConfigChange to 'apply' the changes done
into the registry.
The good thing is that it seems much faster than using WMI, the
bad is that it is an undocumented function.
It would be better that Microsoft make WMI to work correctly.